# getting International Mobile Subscriber Identity (IMSI) in win32 application

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, gsm, cdma

I am developing a application, where I need to display the IMSI number from data card which has been plugged in to a vista system.I am using visual studio 2005 and microsoft SDK.

Is there any way to access the IMSI number of the data card(both GSM and CDMA) using any win32 api or any other way to access it

thanks in advance
Vinayaka Karjigi

Answer (score 0):

Try to query your mobile device via AT commands using the usually installed serial interface (emulator). If supported, AT+CIM should give you the SIM IMSI.

Comment: AT command wont work when Data card is connected.
but i need a way where IMSI can be accessed any time(data card connected or not connected).

Comment: Well, then you maybe must take the route of writing sort of a device driver. Or you read and store the IMSI every time before opening a data connection so you have the cached information available.

The IMSI is a property of the SIM card and will not change over time.